# Search text with double quotes - Elasticsearch

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I want to find the text wrapped in quotation marks, for example:

`"example text"`

The text inside the quotation marks will not always be the same, it can also be, for example, the following:

`"example phrase"`

It is important that the searched text is wrapped in quotation marks.

I tried the following query:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query" : {
    "regexp" : {
      "section_content" : {
        "value" : "\"[A-Za-z ]* Area\""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to find phrases such as "Office Area", "Warehouse Area", but this query returns nothing.

Answer (score 2):

## Tldr;

It is a tricky bit. Because you are playing with 2 notions.

1. How Elasticsearch store text, the most common are `keyword` and `text` type

You are going to want to store your text as `keyword`. As `text` [imply some analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/configure-text-analysis.html) on elasticsearch side.

> By default, Elasticsearch uses the standard analyzer for all text analysis. The standard analyzer gives you out-of-the-box support for most natural languages and use cases ...

2. How to escape char in `regexp` in elasticsearch.

You need to use `\\\` because the playload in embeded in json.

## A demo

```
POST /73123648/_doc
{
  "value": """ this is a nice "Office Area" is it not ?"""
}

POST /73123648/_doc
{
  "value": """ I disposed of it at the "Wharehouse Area", don't worry."""
}

POST /73123648/_doc
{
  "value": """I did not put quotes around Office Area or Wharehouse area this time"""
}

GET 73123648/_search
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "value.keyword": {
        "value": ".*\\\"[A-Za-z]+ Area\\\".*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. But what if I need to store the text as "text" because I need it in that form for other queries. Do you think the best solution would be to store the text both as "text" and as "keyword"? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: I have added a new section_content_keyword field of type "keyword" and tried to search according to the example you gave for the phrase in quotation marks, but unfortunately I still don't get a result.